# How to generate and post html table Grid data to mvc controller as array

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

If I input data to the table I want to get the data as array in mvc controller.
I want to pass input values of each row and column to controller as an array.
so i can perform various operations on array

```
function createTable()
{
    document.getElementById('tb_container').innerHTML = "";
    var rows = document.getElementById('tb_rows').value;
    var cols = document.getElementById('tb_cols').value;

    tblHtml = '<table>'
    for (i = 0; i < rows; i += 1)
    {
        tblHtml += '<tr>';
        for (j = 0; j < cols; j += 1)
        {
            tblHtml += '<td><input type="text"></td>';
        }
        tblHtml += '</tr>';
    }
    tblHtml += '</table>';
    document.getElementById('tb_container').innerHTML = tblHtml;
}



td {
    min-width: 100px;
    min-height: 20px;
    border: solid 1px #000;
}




<ul>
    <li>
        Rows:
        <input type="text" id="tb_rows">
    </li>
    <li>
        Columns :
        <input type="text" id="tb_cols">
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="button" value="Create Table" onclick="createTable()">
    </li>
</ul>

<div id="tb_container"></div>
```

please suggest me how should i pass the input data (i.e values in rows and columns) from user as array.

Comment: Are you trying to generate grid table dynamically based on user inputs ?

Comment: You need to write two loops, one for the rows and one for columns and you can render the x number of  trs and y number tds inside that.

Comment: @stom will you please see the http://jsfiddle.net/EKfut/2/ . i want to pass the table data to the .net mvc controller as arrray .

Comment: Your first question title was `grid-view on basis of input rows and coloums` and i answered that question, now you have changed the question title and this not advisable , if you are new to SO check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help) before asking :)

Comment: ok sir , i will go through it

Comment: Kindly don't call sir, :) , also did you find the answer ?

Comment: @stom no i don't find the answer yet

Comment: I have edited my old answer , please check , Also it would be better next time when asking question , first try to frame good title and ask exact requirement instead of editing and changing your requirement form Jquery to MVC as it would help others to guide better, if you are new to MVC Kindly Learn MVC from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/database-first-development/creating-the-web-application). All the best. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work to generate rows and columns from user input and post those grid data to mvc action method:

**Grid View Models:**

```
public class GridVM
{
    public GridVM()
    {
        GridData = new List<GridData>();
    }
    public int NoOfRows { get; set; }

    public int NoOfColumns { get; set; }

    public List<GridData> GridData { get; set; }
}


public class GridData
{
    public string CellData { get; set; }

    public int NoOfRows { get; set; }

    public int NoOfColumns { get; set; }
}
```

**Grid Get Index Action Method:**

```
public ActionResult Index()
 {

   return View();
 }
```

**Grid Get Index View:**

```
@model Demo.Models.GridVM

<style>
table td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>


<label>No Of Rows</label>

@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.NoOfRows)

<br />

<label>No Of Columns</label>

@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.NoOfColumns)

<button type="button" id="addGrid">Add Grid</button>

<br />

@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveGridData", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
<table id="gridData">

@Html.Partial("_AddGridPartials", new Demo.Models.GridData())

</table>

<br />

<input type="submit" value="Submit Grid Data"/>

}
```

**Add Grid Action Method:**

```
[HttpPost]
public PartialViewResult AddGrid(GridVM addGrid)
 {

  var gridData = new GridData();

  gridData.NoOfRows = addGrid.NoOfRows;
  gridData.NoOfColumns = addGrid.NoOfColumns;

  return PartialView("_AddGridPartials", gridData);

  }
```

**Add Grid Partial View:**

Note: Install `BeginCollectionItem` HtmlHelper from [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BeginCollectionItem/) to have unique `name` attributes in `form` to bind to your model properties.

```
@model Demo.Models.GridData
@using HtmlHelpers.BeginCollectionItem


@for (var i = 0; i < Model.NoOfRows; i++)
{


<tr>

@for (var j = 0; j < Model.NoOfColumns; j++)
{
 using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("gridData"))
  {
    <td>
     @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CellData)
    </td>
  }
}

</tr>

<br />

}
```

**Save Grid Data Action Method:**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveGridData(GridVM gridDetails)
 {

  var gridDataArray = gridDetails.GridData.ToArray();

  // Or you can loop through the list save using you repository

  foreach (var data in gridDetails.GridData)
    {
      var cellValue = data.CellData;

      // TODO save cellValue using your repository

    }

  return Json(new { Message = "Done!, All Details Saved" },JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

  }
```

**Add Grid Script:**

```
   <script>

   $(document).ready(function () {

    var gridDetails = $('#gridData');
    $('#addGrid').click(function () {

        var gridObject = new Object();
        gridObject.NoOfRows = $("#NoOfRows").val();
        gridObject.NoOfColumns = $("#NoOfColumns").val();


        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("AddGrid", "Home")',
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
            data: JSON.stringify({ addGrid: gridObject }),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function(data) {
                if (data) {
                    gridDetails.append(data);
                }
            },
            error: function(jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(errorThrown);
            }
        });
    })

    });

   </script>
```